# Ruby: How to make a public static method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Java I might do:

```
public static void doSomething();
```

And then I can access the method statically without making an instance:

```
className.doSomething();
```

How can I do that in Ruby? this is my class and from my understanding `self.` makes the method static:

```
class Ask

  def self.make_permalink(phrase)
    phrase.strip.downcase.gsub! /\ +/, '-'
  end

end
```

But when i try to call:

```
Ask.make_permalink("make a slug out of this line")
```

I get:

```
undefined method `make_permalink' for Ask:Class
```

Why is that if i haven't declared the method to be private?

Comment: Are you sure it's not under a `private` heading? It might be much higher up than where you put your new method, so just something to double check.

Comment: @MrDanA it's not under private. positive about that

Comment: Then your code isn't being loaded correctly, because that method looks fine.

Comment: I couldn't post an answer because this question was closed, but you have to require the class from the file you are calling from. So in your other class that you make a call to the static method, include this line: `require 'Ask'`, with the path to the Ask.rb file if necessary.

Comment: @Chloe Read the OP's error message. `undefined method` means that the class is known but the method is not. If the class is not known, then the interpreter will produce `uninitialized constant Ask`.

Comment: Clearly, there´s another object called `Ask` somewhere else on the code (and doesn´t have the correct definition on the example)

Comment: `self.` doesn't make the method static, rather will add the method to the singleton object of the class refer: https://abdulrahmank.github.io/main/2020/03/26/static-methods-in-ruby.html

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Your given example is working very well

```
class Ask
  def self.make_permalink(phrase)
    phrase.strip.downcase.gsub! /\ +/, '-'
  end
end

Ask.make_permalink("make a slug out of this line")
```

I tried in 1.8.7 and also in 1.9.3
Do you have a typo in you original script?

All the best

Comment: How do you know the definition and the call are in the same file?

Comment: @Chloe that is an example how to call. did you downvote for that reason?

Comment: @Chloe copy the example in an irb and send the output

Answer (score 32):

There is one more syntax which is has the benefit that you can add more static methods

```
class TestClass

  # all methods in this block are static
  class << self
    def first_method
      # body omitted
    end

    def second_method_etc
      # body omitted
    end
  end

  # more typing because of the self. but much clear that the method is static
  def self.first_method
    # body omitted
  end

  def self.second_method_etc
    # body omitted
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's nice if you don't want the messy self. on every method.

Answer (score 8):

Here's my copy/paste of your code into IRB. Seems to work fine.

```
$ irb
1.8.7 :001 > class Ask
1.8.7 :002?>   
1.8.7 :003 >   def self.make_permalink(phrase)
1.8.7 :004?>     phrase.strip.downcase.gsub! /\ +/, '-'
1.8.7 :005?>   end
1.8.7 :006?>   
1.8.7 :007 > end
 => nil 
1.8.7 :008 > Ask.make_permalink("make a slug out of this line")
 => "make-a-slug-out-of-this-line"
```

Seems to work. Test it out in your `irb` as well, and see what results you're getting. I'm using 1.8.7 in this example, but I also tried it in a Ruby 1.9.3 session and it worked identically.

Are you using MRI as your Ruby implementation (not that I think that should make a difference in this case)?

In `irb` make a call to `Ask.public_methods` and make sure your method name is in the list. For example:

```
1.8.7 :008 > Ask.public_methods
 => [:make_permalink, :allocate, :new, :superclass, :freeze, :===, 
     ...etc, etc.]
```

Since you also marked this as a `ruby-on-rails` question, if you want to troubleshoot the actual model in your app, you can of course use the rails console: (`bundle exec rails c`) and verify the publicness of the method in question.

Answer (score 0):

I am using ruby 1.9.3 and the program is running smoothly in my irb as well.

```
1.9.3-p286 :001 > class Ask
1.9.3-p286 :002?>     def self.make_permalink(phrase)
1.9.3-p286 :003?>         phrase.strip.downcase.gsub! /\ +/, '-'
1.9.3-p286 :004?>       end
1.9.3-p286 :005?>   end
 => nil 
1.9.3-p286 :006 > Ask.make_permalink("make a slug out of this line")
 => "make-a-slug-out-of-this-line"
```

It's also working in my test script. Nothing wrong with your given code.It's fine.