# How does [ ] work on a class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

I see that I can get a list of files in a directory using

```
Dir["*"]
```

How am I supposed to read that syntax exactly ? As I know that you can use **[ ]** to fetch a value from a array or a hash.

How does [ ] work on a call ?

Comment: Looks like its just syntactic sugar, an alias for `Dir.glob([string,...],0)` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html

Comment: [Dir::[\]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-5B-5D) is a garden-variety method. To define it on your own class: `class A; def [](other); puts other; end; end; A.new['cat'] => "cat"`.

Comment: for your second point -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767240/ruby-how-to-make-a-public-static-method

Comment: Please remove the second part of your question. Questions on SO must be about one issue. If another issue is found, it is best to (a) update your question/title to reflect the new issue, or (b) open up a new post. I suggest the latter, as you have solved your original answer.

Comment: I know you have selected an accepted answer, but you may find mine helpful, specifically with `Dir["*"]`

Comment: Yes, I did thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Ruby Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html), `Dir["*"]` is equivalent to `Dir.glob(["*"])`. (As pointed out, it's [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar))

`Dir` isn't a call, it's a class, and objects of `class Dir` are directory streams, which you access like an array.

In your specific case, `Dir["*"]` will return an `array` of filenames that are found from the pattern passed as `Dir[patternString]`. `"*"` as a pattern will match zero or more characters, in other words, it will match everything, and thus will return an `array` of all of the filenames in that directory.

For your second question, you can just [define it as any other method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13767240/ruby-how-to-make-a-public-static-method) like so:

```
class YourClass
  def self.[](v)
    #your code here
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, that cleared it up. I have updated my question. Any thoughts of the second part of it ?

Comment: @cremno, you're right, thanks for pointing that out, I'll update

Comment: @PrakashRaman I've updated the question again now that you reworded the second question :)

Answer (score 5):

`[]` is simply a method, like #to_s, #object_id. etc.

You can define it on any object:

```
class CoolClass
  def [](v)
    puts "hello #{v}"
  end
end

CoolClass.new["John"] # => "hello John"
```

In your case it's defined as singleton method, in this way:

```
class Dir
  def self.[](v)
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The method [`Dir::glob`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html) takes an argument, and provides an array of all directories *and* files nested under the argument. (From there, you can grab the index of the array with `[0]`.) The argument may include a pattern to match, along with flags. The argument (pattern, flags) may be options *similar* (but not exactly) regular expressions.

From the docs, including a couple of patterns/flags that may be of interest to you:

> Note that this pattern is not a regexp, it's closer to a shell glob. See [`File.fnmatch`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/File.html#method-c-fnmatch) for the meaning of the flags parameter. Note that case sensitivity depends on your system (so `File::FNM_CASEFOLD` is ignored), as does the order in which the results are returned.
>
> - **`*`** - Matches any file. Can be restricted by other values in the glob. Equivalent to `/ .* /x` in regexp.
> - **`[set]`** - Matches any one character in set. Behaves exactly like character sets in [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Regexp.html), including set negation (`[^a-z]`).

The shorthand of `Dir::glob()` is `Dir[]`, although I prefer the long form. As you saw above, using brackets denotes a special pattern/flag for the argument. Here are some examples (from the docs) that may better explain this:

```
Dir["config.?"]                     #=> ["config.h"]
Dir.glob("config.?")                #=> ["config.h"]
Dir.glob("*.[a-z][a-z]")            #=> ["main.rb"]
Dir.glob("*")                       #=> ["config.h", "main.rb"]
```

It is possible for you to redefine the `[]` method for `Dir`, but I will not show how -- many (and myself) do not recommend monkey-patching core Ruby classes and modules. However, you can create the method in a class of your own. See the following:

```
class User
  # Class method => User.new[arg]
  def self.[](arg)
  end

  # Instance method => @user[arg]
  def [](arg)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`Dir` is an object just like any other object (it just happens to be an instance of class `Class`), and `[]` is a method just like any other method (it just happens to have a funny name, and special syntactic conveniences that allow it to called using a different syntax in addition to the normal one).

So, you define it just like any other method:

```
class MyClass
  def self.[](*) end
end
```